# laravel vue js component unable to compile

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am new to laravel-VUE and is on a learning journey. Will appreciate any help.
Laravel comes with VUE, all Vue components are registered in an app.js file like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('apnavbar-component', require('./components/APnavbarComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('group-component', require('./components/GroupComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('product-component', require('./components/ProductComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

In home.blade.php i have this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<apnavbar-component></apnavbar-component>
<group-component></group-component>
<product-component></product-component>
@endsection
```

In APnavbarComponent.vue I have this:

```
<template>
<h1>ap navbar component</h1>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'test message'
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("apnavbarcomponent mounted");
    }
}
</script>
```

this is the error message displayed in npm run watch console:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?
{"id":"data-v-b62d55fa","hasScoped":false,"buble":
{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js? 
type=template&index=0!./resources/js/components/APnavbarComponent.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
  Error compiling template:

  <h1>ap navbar component</h1>
  { message }

  - text "{ message }" outside root element will be ignored.
```

npm cannot compile this, and when I remove {{ message }}, it compiles and when i try to console.log the message, npm fails to compile again. Why is this so? Appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue can only have 1 root element inside of `<template>`

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/09/11/vue-multiple-root-fragments/

> Typically, you'll fix this problem by adding a "wrapper" div as a
>   parent. This wrapper element has no display purpose, it's just there
>   so your template complies with the single-root requirement.

Comment: oh my, thank you so much! adding a div after the template to wrap everything in made it work!